# Positioning buttons under slideshow in CSS

Tags: css, button, position, slideshow

I am trying to re-position some navigation tools in CSS but anything I try doesn't work. Is there a way I could group it together and move it as a `div`?
I've tried adjusting the background properties and also playing with `padding` and `margin`s of the individual tags. I'm not sure how else it can be done?

This is the code i'm working with:

```
#slides .slidesjs-navigation {
      margin-top:5px;
    }

    a.slidesjs-next,
    a.slidesjs-previous,
    a.slidesjs-play,
    a.slidesjs-stop {
      background-image: url(images/btns-next-prev.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      display:block;
      width:12px;
      height:18px;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-indent: -9999px;
      float: left;
      margin-right:5px;

    }

    a.slidesjs-next {
      margin-right:10px;
      background-position: -12px 0;

    }

    a:hover.slidesjs-next {
      background-position: -12px -18px;
    }

    a.slidesjs-previous {
      background-position: 0 0;
    }

    a:hover.slidesjs-previous {
      background-position: 0 -18px;
    }

    a.slidesjs-play {
      width:15px;
      background-position: -25px 0;
    }

    a:hover.slidesjs-play {
      background-position: -25px -18px;
    }

    a.slidesjs-stop {
      width:18px;
      background-position: -41px 0;
    }

    a:hover.slidesjs-stop {
      background-position: -41px -18px;
    }
```

It's sitting in the bottom of the page! I would like it to sit just beneath the slideshow of images! Any help would be great!

Comment: Please post the HTML as well.

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        
        play: {
          active: true,
          auto: true,
          interval: 6000,
          swap: true
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

Comment: Could you please add the HTML that the CSS will be styling?